# Unable to scale down mui button size for mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I'm struggling to dim the size of buttons with makeStyles hook and newest version of Mui. And whatever kind of property I try to give to my buttons they won't get any narrower than 64px wide in mobile view (media queried ). Do I have to override root theme to achieve my goal?

```
<Grid container spacing={0} justify="center" className={classes.nav_mobile}>
                
                <Grid container spacing={0} item sm={12} direction="row" justify="space-evenly" >
                        <a href="/home"><Button className={classes.button_mobile}>Home</Button></a>
                </Grid>
                
                
            </Grid>
```

makeStyle hook:

```json
button_mobile: {
        padding: "0",
        fontFamily: ["Comfortaa" , "cursive"],
        fontSize: '1.5vw',
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
        width: ['8vw', '!important'],
        height: "2vh",
        boxShadow: "none",
        color: "#30786E",
        margin: " 0",
```

Comment: Can you include a codesandbox for this?

Comment: @bertdida here you go

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-khayyam-qlxxw?file=/Header.jsx

Comment: Thanks. What we're trying to achieve here again? When the screen is `> 768px` you want the button to have `min-width: 64px`?

Comment: No. Maybe i copied wrong jss. When the screen < 768 I want the button to have max width of somewhat around 50px only. The thing is 64px is the minimum I could get

Comment: And from 64px they only get wider not narrower. Trying to figure out what Mui class is causing this.

Comment: `.MuiButton-root` has `min-width: 64px`. You can add `minWidth: "auto"` to your `button_mobile` style to override that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @bertdida.
The `.MuiButton-root` has `min-width: 64px`.
I just added new `min-width` property and it solved things.